# Google Glass GDK - CardScrollAdapter getHomePosition not working

Tags: java, android, google-glass

In the official GDK documentation for the CardScrollAdapter ([link](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/widget/CardScrollAdapter)) it states that you can override `public int getHomePosition()` to have your adapter define a new "home" position (aka: The view that is initially displayed when the parent CardScrollView is displayed/activated). The problem is... I've attempted to do this but `public int getHomePosition()` never appears to be called by the adapter.

Here is a simplified example...

```
public abstract class StackOverflowExample extends CardScrollAdapter
{
    private Context m_context = null;

    public StackOverflowExample(Context context)
    {
        super();
        m_context = context;
    }

    @Override public final int getCount()
    {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override public int getHomePosition()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    // Other misc adapter overrides here...

    @Override public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Card glassCard = new Card(m_context);
        glassCard.setText("Position: " + position);
        return glassCard.getView(view, parent);
    }
}
```

When I initialize and assign this adapter to a CardScrollView and then `activate()` it, the first card displayed is "Position: 0".

My question is, am I using `getHomePosition()` incorrectly or does it simply not work as expected in the latest Glass Development Kit Preview release?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually used `getHomePosition()`, but I have gotten the same functionality you are describing by using `mCardScrollView.setSelection(homePosition)`right after setting the content view. If you haven't gotten this working by now, this might help.

EDIT: After looking through the docs, I think they meant the overridden function to be used like this:

```
mCardScrollView.setSelection(getHomePosition())
```

Otherwise it would make more sense to call it `setHomePosition()`